# rsnapshot backup not working?

Tags: rsync, backup, rsnapshot, rdiff-backup, rdiff

I installed `rsnapshot` and configured it to make backup every hour. But the issue is all backups that are made not working. Let me explain to you, I made 3 backups `hourly.0`, `hourly.1` and `hourly.2`.

- hourly.0 : there are 15 files
- hourly.1 : there are 14 files (I removed one file)
- hourly.2 : there are 15 files (I recreated an other file)

The problem is when I went to backup of `hourly.1` I found the file that I created in `hourly.2`, so I tried to remove it again but unfortunately the file that I removed ended up being removed in all my folders (`hourly.0`, `hourly.1` and `hourly.3`), which means the all of those folders are just a symbolic links not more.

This is my file configuration:

```
  #rsnapshot
  config_version    1.2
  snapshot_root /var/Majjane-Save/
  cmd_cp        /bin/cp
  cmd_rm        /bin/rm
  cmd_rsync /usr/bin/rsync
  cmd_logger    /usr/bin/logger
  cmd_du        /usr/bin/du
  cmd_rsnapshot_diff    /usr/bin/rsnapshot-diff
  retain        hourly  24
  verbose       2
  loglevel  3
  logfile   /var/log/rsnapshot.log
  lockfile  /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
  exclude       /var/www/clients/
  exclude       /var/www/apps/
  backup    /var/www/   localhost/var/Majjane-Save/
```

Note : i  solved the issue , in the fact it was about the symbolic links. i were run the backup just the symbolic links no more. now its work well.

Comment: Do not remove or edit files in the `hourly.*` directories. They belong to `rsnapshot`.

Comment: i know , i mean i remove the file from the originale folder that i backuped it

Comment: Is it possible you are confusing how rsnapshot is numbering things. hourly.2 is the first snapshot and hourly.0 is the most recent.

Comment: Please find a file that is linked incorrectly within you backup sets, and provide `ls -l` for each instance of it. Please also confirm the filesystem type (ext4, FAT,etc.) on which your backups are placed.

Comment: @StrongBad i know that ^^

Comment: It would be helpful then if you said when you created, deleted, and modified files and what is where at different time points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the timeline of events.

1. The first backup made by `rsnapshot` will be `hourly.0`.
2. When the second backup is made by `rsnapshot`, it first renames `hourly.0` to `hourly.1` and the proceeds to create a new `hourly.0`.
3. When the third backup is made by `rnapshot`, it first renames `hourly.1` to `hourly.2`, renames `hourly.0` to `hourly.1`, and then creates `hourly.0`.

Thus the oldest (first) backup in this scenario is now called `hourly.2` and the newest (most recent) is always called `hourly.0`.

Links are made between the backups, so that the file `hourly.0/data/etc/hosts` might well be the *same file* as `hourly.1/data/etc/hosts` and `hourly.2/data/etc/hosts`. If you were then to edit the real `/etc/hosts`, the next backup would not link to the existing `hourly.1/data/etc/hosts` but would proceed to take a fresh copy of `/etc/hosts` as `hourly.0/data/etc/hosts`.